# software-properties-gtk will not open

Tags: package-management, python, software-center

I followed all the questions about this item but none of them gave me a solution. Can someone help me?

Ubuntu 19.04
output of software-properties-gtk:

```
wim@PC-kamer:~$ software-properties-gtk
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.209:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();

 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)

 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
and tried 
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.209 was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: Does it work from Synaptic Package Manager, /settings/repositories?

Comment: It is also not working from Synaptic. I reinstall in Synaptic the program but stil not working.  It appears in the launcher but is not reacting when clikking on it.

Comment: scratching my head... I don't have any ideas for you to check... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by missing or broken Python packages.

First, check which packages are missing, run:
`sudo journalctl -u dbus -f`
JournalCTL is the logging program for accessing Systemd logs, `-u` is the Unit that you want to view the logs for, `-f` means 'follow', it will remain open and print new logs until you close it.

Open a new terminal and try running `software-properties-gtk`, your first terminal will receive the Python error telling you which packages are missing:

```bsh
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC dbus-daemon[3736]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' requested by ':1.1926' (uid=1000 pid=408791 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk " label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC dbus-daemon[3736]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties'
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/usr/lib/software-properties/software-properties-dbus", line 68, in <module>
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     server = SoftwarePropertiesDBus(bus, datadir=datadir)
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/dbus/SoftwarePropertiesDBus.py", line 66, in __init__
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     self._livepatch_service = LivepatchService()
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/LivepatchService.py", line 93, in __init__
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     self._session = requests_unixsocket.Session()
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: NameError: name 'requests_unixsocket' is not defined
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: Error in sys.excepthook:
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     from apport.report import Report
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     import apport.fileutils
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 12, in <module>
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     import os, glob, subprocess, os.path, time, pwd, sys, requests_unixsocket
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     import requests
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: Original exception was:
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/usr/lib/software-properties/software-properties-dbus", line 68, in <module>
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     server = SoftwarePropertiesDBus(bus, datadir=datadir)
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/dbus/SoftwarePropertiesDBus.py", line 66, in __init__
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     self._livepatch_service = LivepatchService()
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/LivepatchService.py", line 93, in __init__
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]:     self._session = requests_unixsocket.Session()
Sep 18 00:33:42 Tiles-PC com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[408804]: NameError: name 'requests_unixsocket' is not defined
```

You are looking for the `ModuleNotFoundError`, in my case `requests` and `requests_unixsocket` are missing or broken.

Reinstall the missing/broken packages:
`sudo apt install python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket --reinstall`

Try running `software-properties-gtk` again. You may need to repeat the process multiple times if further packages are broken.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom of the output of 
wim@PC-kamer:~$ software-properties-gtk 
there is the error:
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.209 was not provided by any .service files

Is it safe to reinstall :
dBus
dBus-user-session
dbus-x11
python-dbus
python3-dBus
python3-dBus.mainloop.qt
ubuntu-system-service

anyone?